# How to execute a function with parameters in dapper

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dapper

Please assist executing a dapper function below. I am using oracle
Below query complains that its missing a FROM, but when from is added, it complains that the query is not properly created.

```
 var user = connection.Query<dynamic>("select myfunctionname(:Username, :Password)", new { Username = input.Username, Password = input.Password },commandType: CommandType.Text).First();
```

Comment: @Steve I get "Not all variables are bound" error

Comment: Note: there is a `QueryFirst<T>` method, and it is almost always preferable to avoid `dynamic`

Comment: Dapper doesn't modify the query, it sends it directly to the database for execution. Have you tried running that query by itself? If *Oracle* complains that FROM is missing, you probably need to add it

Comment: `Not all variables are bound` that's a completely different error from what you posted in the question. What is the *actual* error?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question asked was what happens when I remove CommandType.Text to StoredProcedure then I said I get an error "Not all variables are bound"

Answer (score 1):

If Oracle functions work like SQL Server table-valued functions (UDFs), then you *probably* mean `select * from myfunctionname(:Username, :Password)`